# Archiving scenarios and revisiting stories

Tags: agile, scrum

Working on a large and complex application, I wonder where and whether we should be storing scenarios to document how the software works.

When we discuss problems with an existing feature, it's hard to see what we have already done and it would be hard to look back with a scrum tool such as *TFS*.  We have some tests but these are not visible to the product owner.  
Should we be looking to pull out some vast story / scenario list, amending / updating as we go or is this not agile.

We have no record of how the software works other than the code, some unit tests,some test cases and a few out of date user guides.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tend to use our automated acceptance tests to document this.  As we work on a user story we also develop automated tests and this is part of our Definition of Done.

We use SpecFlow for the tests and these are written as Given, When, Then scenarios that are easy to read and understand and can be shared with the product owners.

These tests add a lot of value as they are our automated regression suite so regression testing is quicker and easier, but as they are constantly kept up to date as we develop new stories they also act as documentation of how the system works.

You might find it useful to have a look at a few blogs around Specification by Example which is essentially what we are trying to do.

A few links I found useful in the past are:

http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/specification-example

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SpecificationByExample.html

Comment: Very interesting thank you.  We have just got to the point of having automated tests but we have limited the exercise to a few regression tests hoping to build out a regression suite.  However you suggest that you automate as a matter of course?

Comment: Automating tests is certainly a conversation we have for each story and we assess the value in automating. For some stories we won't automate because although it would be technically possible the effort wouldn't outweigh the value and we agree to leave the tests as purely manual. 

We try to keep front end UI driven tests to a minimum and use these to test user journeys through the system and then try to add the bulk of the functional tests at the service layer. Trying to following the Automated Testing Pyramid idea (martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the tests we used also a Wiki for documentation. Especially the REST API was documented with request/response examples but also other software behaviour (results from long discussions, difficult to remember stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to match a description of what you've done to the running software, then it sounds like you should put that in version control along with the software. Start with a docs/ directory, then add detail as you need it. I do this frequently, and it just works. If you want to make this web-servable, then set up a web server somewhere to check out the docs every so often and point the document root at the working copy docs/ directory.